# Export result of Mongodb query to file

Tags: json, mongodb, export

I need to export mongodb aggregation query result to file. I am connected to remote server so I need something like `db.myCollection.aggregate([...]).printToFile('C:\Downloads\resultFile.txt')` Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add quotes to your connection string and use `printjson()` to print JSON objects.  Note that the `aggregate()` returns a cursor and thus you have to loop through them.  If your don't use `forEach`, it only returns top 20.

Here is a one line command.

```
mongo --quiet "mongodb://junior:SECRETPASSWORD@mongo4:9000,mongo5:9000/WebApp?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred" --eval 'db.cars.aggregate([...]).forEach(function(doc) { printjson(doc);})' > output.txt
```

In more readable multi-line format

```
mongo --quiet \
    "mongodb://junior:SECRETPASSWORD@mongo4:9000,mongo5:9000/WebApp?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred" \
    --eval 'db.cars.aggregate([...]).forEach(function(doc) \
        { printjson(doc);})' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that Windows is your operating system based on your sample path. In that case you can use `>` to redirect console command output to a file. To run `aggregate` directly from cmd you can use `mongo` as a client with [--eval](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#scripting) parameter which allows you to run JavaScript code, try something like this:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo --host <yourhost> --port <yourport> --eval "db.myCollection.aggregate([...])" > C:\Downloads\resultFile.txt
```

Comment: What is wrong with this: `mongo --host mongo1 --port 9000 --eval "db.WebApp.find({})" > C:\Downloads\resultFile.txt` it does nothing. any error any result.

Comment: It drives me crazy. This is my connection string. How to use it with --eval please? mongodb://junior:SECRETPASSWORD@mongo4:9000,mongo5:9000/WebApp?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred

Comment: Have you tried this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#mongodb-instance-on-a-remote-host ? Below example works on my machine: `mongo mongodb://192.168.99.100:32768 --eval "db.col.aggregate({$project: { _id: 1 }})" > C:\Downloads\resultFile2.txt`

Comment: Thank you. I made it according @simagix solution.